# Some Xamarin.Forms item templates not showing in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I have seen people with the same problem but in Visual Studio 2015.

The solution given was to go through some folders of which aren't available in my Visual Studio 2017 (due to different versions of visual studio, I presume) and so couldn't fix my problem.

**The Problem**

I want to create a cross-platform app using Xamarin.Forms with Carousel Page.
When I want to add new item through the wizard from the Solution explorer, I only see fewer item templates than expected.

The item templates currently being shown for Xamarin.Forms are ,

Content Page XAML

Content Page C#

Content View XAML

Content View C#

List View Page XAML

Mater Detail Page XAML

Tabbed Page XAML

View Cell XAML

[image: Current View of available item Templates on my Visual Studio 2017]

I can't find a way to get Carousel Page XAML to be shown in the list.
Can anyone help me out. I want to make use of the Carousel Page but through the wizard since I'm still new to xamarin.forms.

**Current Situatuion**

I have Installed Visual Studio Correctly with all the packages required for building Xamarin.Forms apps

I'm on the latest version of Xamarin.Forms 2.5, Visual Studio 2017 version 15.4.4 with .Net framework 4.6.01590, Xamarin version 4.7.10.38, Xamarin.Android SDK 8.0.2.1 and Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK 11.3.0.47

Thanks in advance.